# pandas: read a small random sample from big CSV, according to sampling policy

Tags: python, csv, pandas, random

Very related to [Read a small random sample from a big CSV file into a Python data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258491/read-a-small-random-sample-from-a-big-csv-file-into-a-python-data-frame) .

I have a very big csv, with columns `patient_id,visit_data`. I want to read a small sample from it, but if I sample a patient I want to sample all of his records.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep working with `.csv`, you can read the files in chunks, select and concatenate the pertinent rows from each chunk along the below lines [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
patient_id = id
patient = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    patient = pd.concat([patient, chunk[chunk.patient_id==id])
```

However, I would recommend taking a look at [HDF5 storage](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables) via `pandas` as this allows you to select via queries on indexed data rather than iterating through a file. And there are of course various `sql`-based options [(see basic example)](http://www.datacarpentry.org/python-ecology/08-working-with-sql)