# Selecting random rows (of data) from dataframe / csv file in Python after designating start and end row number?

Tags: python, random, rows

Using the `sample()` function I can get the random rows. Data set having `1000000` rows of data and I want to have a subset of `20000` rows. Importing random lines can be done through this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259008/8966221

## reading a dataset

```
dataset = read_csv(file_path)
```

dataset_sub = dataset.sample(20000, random_state=1)

However I want to select random rows between row number `250000` to `750000`. Any possible solution in that regard?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code works:

```
import random
a=random.sample(range(250000,750000), 20000)
data=dataset.loc[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a DataFrame containing the rows between row number 250000 to 750000, then select 20000 random rows from that.

```
dataset_sub = dataset.loc[250000:750000].sample(20000, random_state=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
dataset = read_csv(file_path)
dataset_sub = dataset.sample(random.randint(250000,750000), random_state=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to randomly extract only say 20,000 rows. I think that argument is also to be entered