# How can I read part of file and write the rest to another file?

Tags: python, file, csv, readline

I have multiple large csv file. How can I read part of each file and write 10% of the data/rows to another file?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do: [mcve].

Comment: See f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258491/read-a-small-random-sample-from-a-big-csv-file-into-a-python-data-frame

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll follow this approach.

Comment: Do you care which 10%?  Or any random 10% will do?

Comment: I prefer either the first or last 10% part of the file. But I believe any random 10% will work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
with open("in.csv") as infile, open("out.csv", "w") as outfile:
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile)):
        if not i % 10:
            outcsv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the writing part. But I need to read the rest of the file in Panda. This is what I added `else:
            pd.read_csv(infile) ` But this error arises: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data` How can I fix it?

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the question. I suspect the `csv.reader` and `pd.read_csv` are going to get in one another way if you do that.

Comment: What does "i" refer to?

Comment: It's for index - the line number.