# Read in n number of random columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 80gb h5 file, and I want to just read say a random set of 1000 columns and assume I do not know the column names. How would we achieve this?

Comment: `df.sample(n=1000,axis=1)`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas That would require loading the entire dataframe first.

Comment: I think this can help so have a look at [read-a-small-random-sample-from-a-big-csv-file-into-a-python-data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258491/read-a-small-random-sample-from-a-big-csv-file-into-a-python-data-frame/22259008#22259008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first know the number of columns in your file. Let's assume 10000 here.

You can then use a combination of [numpy.random](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/routines.random.html) and the `columns` option of [pandas.read_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html):

```
pd.read_hdf('file', columns=sorted(np.random.choice(range(10000), size=1000, replace=False)))
```