# Managing large datasets in Python without running into memory issues

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, data-analysis, large-data

I'm currently working on a data analysis project in Python where I need to handle massive datasets. Although I'm using pandas, a fantastic tool, I encounter memory issues when performing operations on these large datasets.

Specifically, I'm dealing with several gigabytes of CSV files. When I try to read these files into a pandas DataFrame or perform operations like merging grouping or even simple aggregations, my system runs out of memory. This is becoming a significant bottleneck in my project.

Optimizing Pandas Usage:

Are there ways to optimize pandas to handle large datasets more efficiently? For instance, are there specific parameters in `read_csv` or other functions that can reduce memory usage?

Comment: I'd be helpful if you gave any information at all about what that data looks like - columns, number of rows, types, etc. etc.

Comment: You might find this SO post useful [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114)

Comment: You should also mention hardware you are using, if you have 4GB of RAM (as an example), not much that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue in my work as well.

Methods that I have used to deal with out-of-memory errors/time consumed with acting on large data:

1. Reading in a sample of the data: [Reading small random sample into df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258491/read-a-small-random-sample-from-a-big-csv-file-into-a-pandas-data-frame)

   - This method ensures that you keep data integrity while reducing size of dataset that you are acting with.
2. Using the Dask library - designed for working with larger datasets: [Dask Comparison with Pandas](https://pub.towardsai.net/python-pandas-vs-dask-dataframes-a-comparative-analysis-c0f59dad5eeb). [Dask Examples](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html)
3. As someone else commented, you can read the csv in chunks, where chunksize is a parameter in the read_csv method: [read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

I, personally, have only used the first and second method. The first method will definitely work but if you really want to use all your data, try out Dask.